# Do I need to watch "Railgun T" first to understand "Index 3" more easily?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index, a-certain-scientific-railgun

I currently rewatching the *To Aru* series with all spin-offs (have only seen the first 2 *Index* and *Railgun* seasons years ago). My question is, after watching the first 2 seasons of *Index* and *Railgun* and *Accelerator*, should I watch *Railgun T* or *Index 3* first?

I heard *Index 3* is a strong rushed series and really hard to follow if someone doesn't know the novel or the manga. Will *Railgun T* help with that, or is it not of any help to understand *Index 3*? Is it, in the first place, hard to understand?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Watching order for "Toaru Majutsu no Index" and related anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11673/watching-order-for-toaru-majutsu-no-index-and-related-anime)

Comment: Sadly not fully because it only says to watch it in the "normal order" but there are many people that says also the other way (railgun 3 before index 3) i don't really want to know which order one finds better, well i would like a answer to that question to but what i really want to know is, if i would understand index 3 better because i watched railgun 3 and if someone would recommend it, also if index 3 is really so hard to understand like some people are saying.
but i really appreciate you're effort to pin this post.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, I've reworded the question a little bit. The community doesn't decide which should be watched first, but they can give some hints for the readers to decide which one they want to watch first.

Comment: It's not like I understand everything when I watch a series, but I watched Index 3 first and Railgun T later and enjoyed both.

Comment: First thanks for rewriting it, english is not my main language and i'm not really good at it so thanks a lot.

I probably will do the same as you then pablo and watch it in the "normal order". Maybe it is better because i enjoy Railgun more then index and can finish this series (for the time being) with something i enjoy more.

thanks for the Help

Comment: I kind of doubt Railgun T is going to add much, if any, context to Index 3. I haven't watched T, but I've read the manga. It's a spin-off of Index. As such, it's events are fairly dependent on what's happened in Index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A Certain Scientific Railgun T* is unlikely to help you understand *A Certain Magical Index III*. I've watched the anime for Index, and around half the episodes for Railgun T. Additionally, I've read the manga for *A Certain Scientific Railgun*, as well as reviewed summaries for the remaining episodes. I strongly suspect that the remaining episodes will closely follow the manga as the first half of the season did. Thus, I can pretty much infer Railgun T isn't going to help. These arcs pretty much tells their own story, and don't have much to do with the story told in Index.

Trying not to spoil anything, but given the contents of episode 68 of Railgun, I'd actually guess that it'll be helpful to watch *A Certain Magical Index III* first. And watching *A Certain Scientific Accelerator* before *A Certain Scientific Railgun T* will be helpful because some characters from there show up in the second half of Railgun T.

If you need more info, this question has some good answers about watch orders: [Watching order for "Toaru Majutsu no Index" and related anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11673/watching-order-for-toaru-majutsu-no-index-and-related-anime)

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much answers my question completely.

Answer (score 0):

Railgun T overlaps with the timeline of Index II, so Index III is not needed to contextualize. Peronally, Index I and Index II (which you have watched) are sufficient since it offers more understanding of characters such as Touma and Accelerator (he changed a lot after being punched by Touma) than watching Railgun and Railgun S alone.