# Are the "A Certain Magical Index" seasons connected?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index

Can you watch *A Certain Magical Index* season 3 without watching the other seasons first? Do you have to watch them in order? Are all the *Index* seasons connected or is season 3 a new story?

Answer (score 1):

The seasons of the anime adapt the light novel series which tells a single, continuous story following the same set of characters across many volumes. As such it's not recommended that you start with season 3 of the anime, since it assumes you already know who the main characters are and what major events already transpired in the previous story arcs.

Starting with season 1 is generally recommended for any sci-fi/fantasy series with a long, complicated narrative like Index. Missing even one episode can often mean missing crucial information that helps piece together character motivations and plot developments.

Comment: You could probably watch the Railgun series without the main Index series, though I think some knowledge is assumed.

Answer (score 1):

The following Index anime series follow each other sequentially:

1. *A Certain Magical Index* (2008): adapts LN volumes 1-6
2. *A Certain Magical Index II* (2010): adapts LN volumes 7-13
3. *A Certain Magical Index III* (2018): adapts LN volumes 14-22

Yes, the seasons are connected, and you should definitely watch them in order. Even some people who watched the previous two series felt a bit lost with the new series because it's been so long that they'd forgotten some of the details. There's a lot of continuity to keep track of here.

If you're interested in the Railgun series as well (same universe), see also: [How are “A Certain Magical Index” and “A Certain Scientific Railgun” connected?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2675/how-are-a-certain-magical-index-and-a-certain-scientific-railgun-connected)