# In which place of the timeline of Toaru Majutsu no Index series does the Toaru Kagaku No Railgun series happen?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index, a-certain-scientific-railgun

In the timeline of Toaru Majutsu No Index (no the release dates of the series/ovas/specials etc which is a completely different thing) where do the Toaru Kagaku No Railgun series happen?

Comment: Related: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2675/how-are-a-certain-magical-index-and-a-certain-scientific-railgun-connected

Comment: That answer is cool but now there are 2 seasons of Toaru Kagaku No Railgun and that probably was answered before the second season appeared, since it doesnt seem to make a reference to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A Google search would actually get you several timelines for the series**, one of which is shown below: 
[image]

Here, you can see there is an overlap to the events that occurred in 'Toaru Majutsu No Index' and 'Toaru Kagaku No Railgun'.

Here's an even more specific timeline and it *clearly* shows which episodes and arcs these overlaps happen:
[image]

Other timelines are more or less similar.

Sources:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/57uwv8/spoilers_about_the_joint_timeline_of_a_certain/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/toarumajutsunoindex/comments/cclkap/ive_translated_this_awesome_series_timeline/